# Respond two times in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

My React Code

```
<form action="/ContactUs/FormData" method="POST">
...         
</form>
```

and

```
handleSubmit(){
    fetch('/ContactUs/FormData')
    .then((results)=>results.json())
    .then((result)=>{
        if(result.name==='ErrorOccured'){
            this.setState({
                display: 'An Error Occured. Please try again!'
            });
        }
        else{
            this.setState({
                display: 'We have recorded your response '+result.name+ '. Please note your ID: '+ result.id
            });
        }
    })
}
```

My Express Code

```
app.post("/ContactUs/FormData",function(req,res){

}
formResponse.save((err,data)=>{ 
    if(err){
        res.write(JSON.stringify({"name":"ErrorOccured"}));
    }
    else{
        res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    res.redirect("/ContactUs");
});
```

I want that when data is submitted to '/ContactUs/FormData', it should be saved using Mongoose and then the form page should be rendered (two response request in one post method).

How do I achieve this that that the page is also rendered and some json data is also sent to React.

Comment: You can't, not with AJAX at least

Comment: So how can I do this with any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Express should not render the form page. ReactJS should. Express must just reply with any data needed by React to render the form page.

Your scenario should be:

1. React sends the form data
2. Express saves it into the database
3. Once saved, retrieve any data necessary to render the *form page*
4. In express, combine the data for the *form page* and the success/error message from the save operation into one single JS object.
5. Express should send this single object to React through `res.write` (no redirect)
6. React reads the answer, display any error message and/or render the *form page* by displaying data sent by Express

Note that Express can return any kind of data, included information for React to know what page to render next.

Comment: So is there a way for react to render that page?

Comment: ReactJS is design to render pages. I don't know what your _form page_ should look like, but you can build it the same way as your _contact page_. You should probably read React documentation to understand what you can use it for.